# How can I programatically analyze (and change) the configuration of IIS

Tags: windows, iis, scripting, shell, wsh

I'm relatively new to the Windows Server world (coming from *nix land). I'm used to analyzing a web-server's configuration by grepping through an apache config file.

Is there an equivalent file/group-of-files for IIS?  Lacking that, is there an official scripting interface for IIS?

Comment: It would help if you specified which version; IIS6 or 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell would be the way to go.

Here are some stack overflow posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell+iis6

Also, googling **powershell IIS** will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Default scripting tool in IIS is the ADSUTIL.VBS script in the \InetPubs\Scripts directory.

[Using the Adsutil.vbs Administration Script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781546.aspx)

You can pretty much do anything to the IIS metabase with that tool.